# python- searching dictionary sublists; converting dictionary keys to values

Tags: python, search, dictionary, sublist

Say I have the following dictionary (the one I'm using is much, much larger):

```
dict1={1:["item", "word", "thing"], 2:["word", "item"], 3:["thing", "item", "item"]}
```

and have every word used in the dictionary stored in a list:

```
all_words=["item", "word", "thing"]
```

I want to run each word of the list through the dictionary sublists, and return the keys for all sublists in which they are found, storing them in tuples. So I want to get:

```
dict2={"item":(1, 2, 3), "word":(1, 2), "thing":(1, 3)}
```

heres what I have:

```
dict2={}    
for word in all_words:
    for key, sublist in dict2.items():
        for word in sublist:
            if word not in sublist:
                dict2[word]=dict2[word]+key
            else:
                dict2[word]=key
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing that `if word not in sublist:` should be `if word not in dict2:`?

Comment: Why are you iterating over `dict2.items()`?

Comment: One more problem: `dict2[word]+key` doesn't work; you can't add a `tuple` to an `int`. But `dict2[word] + (key,)` does. And `dict2[word] = (key,)` to make it a tuple in the first place, of course. If you fix this problem, and the other two problems (hint: it might be harder to make mistakes like that if you gave your variables better names than `dict1`…), your code should work. However, you may want to look at the `setdefault` method and/or the `defaultdict` class to make it a little less verbose, easier to read, harder to screw up, and possibly more efficient.

Comment: Just to explicitly point out, you should neither be iterating over `dict2`, nor `dict1.items()`. You should be iterating over just `dict1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, your fixed program, based on the comments would look like this

```
>>> dict2 = {}
>>> for word in all_words:
...     # Iterate over the dict1's items
...     for key, sublist in dict1.items():
...         # If the word is found in the sublist
...         if word in sublist:
...             # If the current word is found in dict2's keys
...             if word in dict2:
...                 # Append the current key as a one element tuple
...                 dict2[word] += (key,)
...             else:
...                 # Create a one element tuple and assign it to the word
...                 dict2[word] = (key,)
... 
>>> dict2
{'item': (1, 2, 3), 'word': (1, 2), 'thing': (1, 3)}
```

If you know about dictionary comprehension, then the same can be written as

```
>>> {word: tuple(k for k, v in dict1.items() if word in v) for word in all_words}
{'item': (1, 2, 3), 'word': (1, 2), 'thing': (1, 3)}
```

The whole tuple creation logic, based on the `dict1` for every corresponding `word`, has been squeezed as a single generator expression and converted to a tuple with `tuple(k for k, v in dict1.items() if word in v)`

Answer (score 3):

Your code's logic is incorrect, because you are iterating over 3 objects while you just need to iterate over your dictionary and revers the position of key and values but as you may have duplicated values you can use a `set` container for preserving the corresponding keys for each name. [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is a great tool for this such situations:

```
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in dict1.items():
...    for k in j:
...      d.setdefault(k,set()).add(i)
... 
>>> d
{'item': set([1, 2, 3]), 'word': set([1, 2]), 'thing': set([1, 3])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are looping `dict2.items` whereas it should be `dict1.items`. Also you are not *appending* the keys into the `dict2` values if found, you just reassign the values to the last key found in `dict1` values. Thus the `dict2` values are not what you expected.

Instead you can alternatively use `collections.defaultdict` (or use solution from @Kasra, @thefourtheye):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict2 = defaultdict(tuple)

for word in all_words:
    for key, sublist in dict1.iteritems(): # this 
        if word in sublist:
            dict2[word] += (k,)
        else:
            dict2[word] = (k,)

dict2
Out[3]: defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'item': (1, 2, 3), 'word': (1, 2), 'thing': (1, 3)})
```